# Is it bad practice for a controllers actions to have differing authorization levels?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, single-responsibility-principle

We are developing a website and we have a controller that handles CRUD for a model e.g Country. Only the Administrator is allowed to perform CRUD operations. However we also want the controller to provide a JSON select list of entities to populate a drop-down. This pattern exists through out the application.

This means that we can't use the standard authorization attribute to restrict access to administrators at the entry to the controller. We need to decorate each action with specific authorize attribute.

Is the fact that we need multiple authorization levels on a single controller a bad sign? Does it suggest we are violating SRP?

What is the best pattern to deal with the fact many controllers relate to entities that need to be updatable only by Admin but provide a JSON select list for all authorized users?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with doing this is the Risk that you might forget to protect an action that is supposed to be admin only.

Really the preferred way to approach this problem is to have an admin-only area on your site (using MVC areas).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx

http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/asp-net-mvc-areasa-better-way-to-structure-the-application/

This way the entire www.site.com/admin section would be protected as admin-only.

Comment: Yeah that was partly my concern that it was easy to get authorization wrong doing it this way.